# Разделить изображение на строки

Tags: python, java, изображения, обработка-изображений

Существует ли возможность разделить изображение на строки, т.е. данное изображение
[image: общий чек]

разделить на отдельные строки ==> так [image: одна единица заказа из чека]

Comment: Я бы попробовал просуммировать яркость в каждой строке пикселов. В промежутках между строками чека будет повышенная сумма яркости пикселов. Проблема в том, что строки в чеке имеют наклон, придётся пробовать разный наклон строк подбирать плюс-минус на несколько пикселов с одной стороны в поисках максимальной яркости. Но мне кажется должно работать.

Comment: Руководствуясь Вашим советом, я попробовал указанный подход (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51667166/how-to-split-the-image-into-chunks-without-breaking-character-python), он отлично работает для отсканированной страницы книги, но для чека - нет.
Я попробовал преобразовать картинку чека BGR2GRAY, увеличить контрастность с помощью cv2.threshold(gray_image, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) увеличить размер картинки в пикселях с помощью cv2.resize() => нет, не помогает.
Пробема думаю в том, что надо выровнять чек, но как это сделать не имея шаблона для выравнивания?

Comment: Так я же говорю - нужно попробовать разный наклон. Грубо говоря слева начинаем идти по строке, а справа мы должны прийти например на +1 пиксел ниже. Для этого нужно пол-строки идти по той же строке, а вторую половину строки идти на пиксел ниже. И вот перебрать такие варианты чтобы приходить на один или несколько пикселов выше-ниже справа. Тут даже косинусов никаких не нужно, просто посчитать, сколько пикселов идти горизонтально, прежде чем перескочить на соседнюю строчку. И вот среди этих вариантов выбрать тот, который самый яркий. То есть будет чуть усложнённый алгоритм.